# Use Boot Camp drivers from DVD or download?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows, driver

I have an iMac mid-2010. It came with Snow Leopard when I bought it. Now, I'd like to install Windows 7 64-bit on my iMac. Should I install the Boot Camp drivers from the DVDs that came with my computer, or download the drivers using the Boot Camp Assistant that I have now in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have upgraded your operating system to Mountain Lion, I would recommend getting the latest drivers from the internet.

While I can't say that they are definitely updated, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29#Version_history) notes that Mountain Lion runs Boot Camp 5 wheres Snow Leopard was version 3.